# Visio Pro : Fill shape with data value that contains A1 or A2

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2019

I tried to change the fill color of a simple rectangle shape with a fixed list data (Visio Pro).
The list contains some values like A1;A2;A3;B1;B2;B3
[PrintScreen for better understanding (sorry in French)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBJmp.png)

I followed the instructions found here (unique values) https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/how-to-use-color-by-value-fa42a92f-019d-4baa-940e-e477b9b9dfeb

I noticed that everything is fine for values like B1, B2, C1 or C2.
But the data graphics doesn't seem to pick up values like A1 or A2 or A+number
Is A+number reserved ? is there a limitation ?

Thanks

Comment: Those values (A1;A2 etc) look more like Excel cells than colour values!

Comment: I don’t understand. Can you explain what you are trying to do a little more clearly?

Comment: I edited my initial post to add a print screen.